# WWF Custom Activity binding for SharePointOnlineCredentials

Tags: c#, xaml, csom, custom-activity

I have created a set of WWF custom activities to interact with SharePoint via the CSOM. I have created the below Activity, however, I am struggling to bind the Arguments in the XAML Designer, I have imported the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace in the XAML file but I am getting the following error (`The name "SharePointOnlineCredentials" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.SharePoint.Client"`) when I try binding the ExpressionType to `sp:SharePointOnlineCredentials`.

Can anyone advise on how I bind the `ExpressionTextBox` `ExpressionType` to be `SharePointOnlineCredentials`?

Note: I realise that some of the code is missing, this is deliberate!

**Activity Class**

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Activities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace Custom_Activities.SharePoint
{
    public sealed class List_To_DataTable : CodeActivity
    {
        [Category("Input")]
        [DisplayName("SharePoint Credentials")]
        public InArgument<SharePointOnlineCredentials> SharePoint_Credentials { get; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            //Gets content

            Dt.Set(context,table);

        }
    }
}
```

**XAML Design**

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner 
    x:Class="CS_Activities.SharePoint.Design.List_To_DataTable_Designer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sapc="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.Converters;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SharePoint.Client">
    <sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1">
            <sapc:ArgumentToExpressionConverter x:Key="ArgumentToExpressionConverter" />
            <sapc:ModelToObjectValueConverter x:Key="ModelToObjectValueConverter" /> 

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment = "Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Text="List Name" />
        <sapv:ExpressionTextBox HintText = "Enter you Sharepoint Credentials" Expression="{Binding Path=ModelItem.SharePoint_Credentials, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=In }" ExpressionType="sp:SharePointOnlineCredentials" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" OwnerActivity="{Binding Path=ModelItem}" Width="300" Margin="0,5" MaxLines="1" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due to the assembly reference missing.

If you look at the class details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) the Namespace is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and the assemvly is `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`

By changing `xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SharePoint.Client"` to `xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;assembly=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime"` the issue is resolved.